# Use CSS to add a character after the text in a list element, but before an indented list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to add with CSS a character to the text in a list element, but before an indented list occurs?
Like, if I have this HTML:

```
  <ul>
      <li>Hola
        <ul>
               <li>Chao</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Use CSS only to add a colon immediately after «Hola», like:

- Hola:

  - Chao

Comment: Perhaps in the future, when [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) is implemented, then you'll be able to target it with `li:has(> ul)`.
Until then, I suggest adding a class to any list item that contains another list.

Comment: @Gil: Even then, you can't easily get the : to appear after the text but before the ul - li:has(> ul)::after would insert it after the ul. This probably requires wrapping the outer li text in a span.

Comment: @BoltClock Good point. Text nodes are invisible to CSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple `jQuery` snippet, you can also do this using pure javascript using `document` object or use this code with `jQuery`. This will help you, I hope.

```js
$("li").map((index, ele) => {
  const content = ele.innerHTML;
  if (index === 0) {
    ele.innerHTML = content.replace(/<ul>/g, ":<ul>");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    Hello
    <ul>
      <li>
        Hello
        <ul>
          <li>
            Hello
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```